# Take 3 random items from a ul and append to another list with random fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, fadein, fadeout

So I have got so far with this function, but now I am struggling with one issue.

I have made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/WhUJq/3/

I have a ul which is hidden the function takes 3 li items from the ul and appends them to a visible ul.

What I want to do is to have a nice fadeIn and fadeOut function on these items. And I was hoping that the fade could be staggered over each li.

This is the function:

```
 function rndSlider() {

var $show = 3, // Number of items to show
    $elemLength = $('.slider li').length, // Total items
    $firstPart = '<li><img src="/img/slider/0',
    $lastPart = '.jpg" /></li>',
    array = [], // array with all available numbers
    rnd, value, i,
    $wrapper = $('.slider-clone');
    $('.slider-clone li').remove();

for (i = 0; i < $elemLength; i++) { 
  array[i] = i + 1;
}

for (i = 0; i < $show; i++) { // pick numbers
  rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length); 
  value = array.splice(rnd,1)[0]; // remove the selected number from the array and get it in another variable

  $wrapper.append($firstPart + value + $lastPart);
  }
}
```

I wondered if I needed an each function on the 
     $('.slider-clone li').remove();
Applied to each li element (I have a fadeIn function working on the fiddle, but not the fadeOut).

And then a fade in on the 
     $wrapper.append($firstPart + value + $lastPart);

But I cannot seem to get anything to work, when I apply one of these, it seems to upset the main function from running.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. well thats awkward.. When i posted this.. it worked well.. I think this issue might have to do with the fadeIn and fadeOut being done async.. The problem here is that when the child images are created the fadeOut effect-callback removes them..

```
$(this).children().remove();
```

I've updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WhUJq/15/

Comment: Awesome thank you so much, I had slightly different code locally as in the fiddle as I had to tweak. But this now looks great. Thanks

Comment: Arrrrrrr, so this is the damnedest thing. The code in the fiddle works fine, when I try and apply it to my live site, it only runs through the function once. And I don't know why. But I have tried so many things. Just to check you only updated the js correct? Sorry. Hope you can help. This is the url: http://www.bmtpromotionalproducts.co.uk/index.php

Comment: I got this working, it was only Chrome that was throwing an issue, upgraded to the latest jquery library and that seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So if i understand you correctly, the problem is the fadeOut() effect?

replace:

```
$('.slider-clone li').each(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(400);                           
});
```

with the following code to solve that issue:

```
$wrapper.fadeOut('slow', function(){ $(this).children().remove(); });
```

Comment: I've updated the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/WhUJq/14/ but it seems to be setting display none on the ul slider-clone whilst the other function is running, as far as I can tell.